# Scrollable position of a TextSpan within a RichText

Tags: flutter, scroll, position, richtext

I have many `TextSpan`s in my `RichText`.
I would like to scroll in a specific `TextSpan`, but for knowing the position I need the context.
`TextSpan` is not a widget.
So how can I get the `TextSpan`'s position?

I can't use `WidgetSpan` because my `Span`s are pieces of the same sentence.

Thanks

Comment: Have you try with SingleChildScrollView ?